# Training of keras model get's slower after each repetition

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm writing some code to optimize a neural net architecture and so have a python function `create_nn(parms)` that creates and initializes a keras model. 
However, the problem I'm having is that after a fewer iterations the models take a lot longer to train than usual (initally one epoch takes 10sec, and then after roughly the 14th model (each model trains for 20 epochs) it takes 60sec/epoch). 
I know that this is not because of the evolving architecture because if I restart the script and start were it ended, it is back to normal speeds.

I'm currently running

```
from keras import backend as K
```

and then a

```
K.clear_session()
```

after training any given new model.

**Some additional details:**

- For the first 12 models, training time per epoch remains roughly constant at 10sec/epoch.  Then at the 13th model training time per epoch climbs steadily to 60sec. Then training time per epoch hovers at around 60sec/epoch.
- I'm running keras with Tensorflow as the backend
- I'm using an Amazon EC2 t2.xlarge instance
- There is plenty of free RAM (7GB free, w/ the dataset of size 5GB)

I've removed a bunch of layers and parameters, but essentially `create_nn` looks like:

```
def create_nn(features, timesteps, number_of_filters):
    inputs = Input(shape = (timesteps, features))
    x = GaussianNoise(stddev=0.005)(inputs)
    #Layer 1.1
    x = Convolution1D(number_of_filters, 3, padding='valid')(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(10)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    # Output layer
    outputs = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

    # Compile and Return
    model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
    print('CNN model built succesfully.')
    return model
```

Note that while a `Sequential` model would've worked in this dummy example, the functional API is required for the actual usecase.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Gonna need some more info to answer this, if you are using a custom function to build your models then you should go over your code and make sure that you aren't creating copies of the model or inadvertently adding a bunch of layers everytime you build a new one.

Comment: @Dimesio Thank you for your comment. I've updated the question with more details about the `create_nn` function. Wouldn't the layers etc. be cleared upon calling `K.clear_session()` or am I mistaken in what `K.clear_session()` does?

Comment: @E.O. I'm not quite sure what `K.clear_session()` does, but since you're using TensorFlow perhaps you'll also need to reset the underlying graph, using `tf.reset_default_graph()`?

Comment: @mrry I've had a look at the Keras source and `clear_session` call `tf.reset_default_graph()` :( Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Hmm That is odd, clear_session() should handle the default graph issue for you, but it seems that your issue is more exponential, as the graph issue was not so much. It might be worth your time to try and call tf.reset_default_graph() manually to see if there is an issue with the function calling it?

Comment: as well, is there any chance that you have the passed variables increasing in size? I could see an exponential increase in time if your features are doubling with each pass-through but it would seem that wouldn't be the case. Worth a look.

Comment: @Dimesio I'll give `tf.reset_default_graph()` a go now. Re doubling of features: I considered that for a while too, but if I restart the program it goes back to normal speed.

Comment: @E.O. thats what I mean, it seems when you restart the program everything resets (including any objects you created to call your functions, ie features)

Comment: I have a similar problem - did you find a solution?

Comment: If you have written your own data loader, the problem could be there. I once had a bug in a custom data loader where it kept returning larger and larger batches, so the epochs were taking longer and longer to run.

Comment: @E.O., did you solve your problem? If so, you could post your solution as an answer to your own question. This will hopefully help people that face this same issue in the future. If you have not solved it, could you please provide more information regarding how you train your model?

Answer (score 6):

## Why is my training time increasing after every run?

Short answer : you need to use `tf.keras.backend.clear_session()` before every new model that you create.

*This problem only seems to happen when eager execution is turned off.*

Okay, so let's run an experiment with and without clear_session.  The code for `make_model` is at the end of this response.

First, let's look at the training time when using clear session.  We'll run this experiment 10 times an print the results

## Use tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

```
non_seq_time = [ make_model(clear_session=True) for _ in range(10)]
```

### With clear_session=True

```
non sequential
Elapse =  1.06039
Elapse =  1.20795
Elapse =  1.04357
Elapse =  1.03374
Elapse =  1.02445
Elapse =  1.00673
Elapse =  1.01712
Elapse =    1.021
Elapse =  1.17026
Elapse =  1.04961
```

As you can see, the training time stays about constant

Now let's re-run the experiment without using clear session and review the training time

## Don't use tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

```py
non_seq_time = [ make_model(clear_session=False) for _ in range(10)]
```

### With clear_session=False

```
non sequential
Elapse =  1.10954
Elapse =  1.13042
Elapse =  1.12863
Elapse =   1.1772
Elapse =   1.2013
Elapse =  1.31054
Elapse =  1.27734
Elapse =  1.32465
Elapse =  1.32387
Elapse =  1.33252
```

as you can see, the training time increases without clear_session

## Full Code Example

```py
# Training time increases - and how to fix it

# Setup and imports

# %tensorflow_version 2.x

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.layers as layers
import tensorflow.keras.models as models
from time import time

# if you comment this out, the problem doesn't happen
# it only happens when eager execution is disabled !!
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()


(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()


# Let's build that network
def make_model(activation="relu", hidden=2, units=100, clear_session=False):
    # -----------------------------------
    # .     HERE WE CAN TOGGLE CLEAR SESSION
    # -----------------------------------
    if clear_session:
        tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

    start = time()
    inputs = layers.Input(shape=[784])
    x = inputs

    for num in range(hidden) :
        x = layers.Dense(units=units, activation=activation)(x)

    outputs = layers.Dense(units=10, activation="softmax")(x)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    results = model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), batch_size=200, verbose=0)
    elapse = time()-start
    print(f"Elapse = {elapse:8.6}")
    return elapse

# Let's try it out and time it

# prime it first
make_model()

print("Use clear session")
non_seq_time = [ make_model(clear_session=True) for _ in range(10)]

print("Don't use clear session")
non_seq_time = [ make_model(clear_session=False) for _ in range(10)]
```