# Tensorflow training time issue with my code

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

Objective: Classify whether a cell is parasitic(malria-ed) or uninfected

Dataset is from Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/iarunava/cell-images-for-detecting-malaria

Imports:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import os

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, MaxPool2D, Conv2D, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

from matplotlib.image import imread
```

Paths:

```
file_path = "/whatever-you-store-the-data/cell_images/"
test_path = "/whatever-you-store-the-data/cell_images/test/"
train_path = "/whatever-you-store-the-data/cell_images/train/"
```

The average size of an image is (130, 130, 3) # (width, height, colour_channels):

```
image_shape = (130, 130, 3)
```

ImageDataGenerator:

```
image_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=20,
                           width_shift_range=0.1,
                           height_shift_range=0.1,
                           shear_range=0.1,
                           zoom_range=0.1,
                           horizontal_flip=True,
                           vertical_flip=True,
                           fill_mode="nearest")
```

The Model:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=image_shape, activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))

model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
              optimizer="adam",
              metrics=["accuracy"])
```

EarlyStopping Callback:

```
early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss",
                           patience=5,
                           verbose=1,
                           mode="min")
```

Generators:

```
train_image_gen = image_gen.flow_from_directory(train_path,
                                                target_size=image_shape[:2],
                                                color_mode="rgb",
                                                batch_size=32,
                                                class_mode="binary")
test_image_gen = image_gen.flow_from_directory(test_path,
                                                target_size=image_shape[:2],
                                                color_mode="rgb",
                                                batch_size=32,
                                                class_mode="binary",
                                               shuffle=False)
```

Fitting the model:

```
results = model.fit_generator(train_image_gen,
                              epochs=20,
                              validation_data=test_image_gen,
                              callbacks=[early_stop])
```

Here is the output:

```
Epoch 1/20
390/Unknown - 9339s 24s/step - loss: 4.4232 - accuracy: 0.5135
```

First of all why is it in the form of n/Unknown, more importantly, why is it taking 9339s. That is not the problem, the problem lies in why the estimated time of training keeps on increasing, it began at somewhere around 240s, it then increases with time until it eventually reached 9339s. What is happening here and how do I solve this?

Comment: Do you have a public notebook you could maybe share?
You might want to check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45796167/training-of-keras-model-gets-slower-after-each-repetition). Hope it helps!

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tRd9MxS5QBWPmKxnx7F4SricPVZP7uSQ

Comment: @Khoo, In your code, you are using `Pickle` Files. But are the Pickle Files present in the site, https://www.kaggle.com/iarunava/cell-images-for-detecting-malaria.