# Tensorflow-GPU performance decreases each epoch on Windows machine

Tags: performance, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm seeing decreasing performance with each subsequent epoch running Tensorflow-GPU with Keras on Windows.

I'm training a 16-layer CNN and load my data using tf.data. The first epoch performs as well as expected: ~1hr training time. The CPU and GPU CUDA load is at 85-90%. Temperatures are reasonable (CPU between 65-70C and GPU at 70C) -- no thermal throttling occurs.

But by the second epoch, GPU CUDA load inexplicably drops to 33-50%. CPU load appears reduced as well, to around 65-75%. I don't see any big change in disk I/O speeds (the data is being loaded from an NVMe SSD).

I don't think this is a hardware issue. I'm using an RTX 3090 and a 4-core i5-6500 CPU and as mentioned, the performance on the first epoch is quite good without enough thermal headroom to continue. My tf.data pipeline looks like this:

```
    # Construct tf.data.Dataset
    paths_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(image_paths)
    if shuffle:
      paths_ds = paths_ds.shuffle(buffer_size=len(image_paths), reshuffle_each_iteration=True)  # reshuffle each epoch
    dataset = paths_ds.map(
      lambda path: (self.load_image(path, scale_range, crop_size, augment), self.get_onehot_label(path, tf_class_index_by_image, self.num_classes)),
      num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
    )
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

A map and a prefetch, both using AUTOTUNE. I suspect maybe AUTOTUNE is the problem but I'm not sure how to debug this and determine how the number of threads and prefetch buffer size might be evolving over time. There is no documentation on how AUTOTUNE works.

EDIT: I did some profiling and have discovered that from epoch 2 onwards, Iterator::MapAndBatch is consuming significant time (it hard to even see in Epoch 1 because the data it collects is always ready). The cause appears to be some sort of perplexing slowness in my "load_image" function. Each operation it performs (read file, decode JPEG, convert to float, resize) is followed by a pause in Epoch 2 onwards and this becomes slower over time.

For example, Epoch 1 with everything functioning correctly:

[image]

Note the read is immediately followed by a decode, etc.

Now in epoch 2:

[image]

What could be causing this? Attempting to elevate the priority of the process using Process Explorer has no effect.

Comment: Have you tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45796167/training-of-keras-model-gets-slower-after-each-repetition/59324250#59324250 ?  In summary: don't turn off eager execution and use keras.backend.clear_session if you are creating new models between runs

Comment: @AntonCodes I only create and train a single model. And I have not touched the eager execution settings. I've noticed that batch size has some impact. If I *increase* the batch size from 128 to 256, I can get through two epochs at normal speeds and then the third one nosedives.

Comment: Until you get a good answer, perhaps a stopgap would be after the first two epochs to save the model, clear the keras session, load the model, then cycle.  If an epoch takes an hour, the time to save+clear+load will be better than living with even a 10% slowdown